# Tail remote files into local file

Tags: logging, ssh, aggregation, tail

I have a few remote logs that I would like to `tail` 24/7 into a local log to keep chronological order of log appending. 
I have 5 upstream servers each running a web application that logs locally into an `app.log` file and a proxy server load balancing requests into the 5 servers. I would like to aggregate each of those app.log files into a single `app.log` file in the proxy server. How would I achieve that? I was thinking of keeping an SSH connection active 24/7 for each server and appending the SSH terminal output into the `app.log` file. Is there a better way of doing so?

Answer (score 0):

There is [Daggy - Data Aggregation Utility](https://daggy.dev).

This is exactly, what do you need. Just create [data aggregation sources](https://docs.daggy.dev/data-aggregation-sources) config like this:

```
aliases:  
    - &my_commands
        pingYa:
            exec: ping ya.ru
            extension: log
        pingGoo:
            exec: ping goo.gl
            extension: log

    - &ssh_auth
        user: {{env_USER}}
        passphrase: {{env_PASSWORD}}

sources:
    localhost:
        type: local
        commands: *my_commands
    remotehost:
        host: 192.168.1.9
        type: ssh2
        parameters: *ssh_auth
        commands: *my_commands
    remotehost2:
        host: 192.168.1.9
        type: ssh2
        parameters: *ssh_auth
        commands: *my_commands
    remotehost3:
        host: 192.168.1.9
        type: ssh2
        parameters: *ssh_auth
        commands: *my_commands
```